# Build nested jquery object and append to inner element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an jquery object:

```
 function build(){
     var first = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'first'
    });
    var second = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'second'
    });
    var third = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'third'
    });
    second.append(third);
    return first.append(second);
}
```

Now I want to append a new element to the third object after it was returned. Tried `obj.find('.third').append(...)` but this is not working.
Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You already have the reference to `third`, so you can just do `third.append('your html here...');`

Comment: I don't get how `obj.find` is related, what did you try to do?

Comment: no. after return. So i get one object ´var obj = buildStuff()...´ reference is gone

Comment: Got a function which returns the object with the 3 divs. Now I want to append some ther objects to the inner div of the returned object.

Comment: In that case we need to see more of your code. What is `obj`? How are you appending `first` to the DOM?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `return first.append(second);` will probably be `obj`.

Comment: Probably, but I don't want to assume these things :)

Comment: Changed the code, yes, its a function. var obj = build(); It is not appended to the DOM. First I need to append more stuff to it before I append it to the DOM. But I need to append to the inner div with class third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `find` method. You can achieve the same with `children()`

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getme(){
    var first = build();
    var fourth = $('<div/>', {
      class: 'fourth'
    });
    first.children().children().append(fourth)
    console.log(first);
}
function build(){
     var first = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'first'
    });
    var second = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'second'
    });
    var third = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'third'
    });
    second.append(third);
    return first.append(second);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="getme()"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edited my code snippet. var obj = build(); Now i want to append to .third of obj.

Comment: Worked :) tried it before with children[0].children[0].append :) Thanks a lot :)